# Automate a csv download from a url using Selenium and Requests

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I have a URL: https://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cell_lines/sample/mutations?id=1287381&sEcho=1&iColumns=10&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&mDataProp_0=0&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&bSortable_0=true&mDataProp_1=1&sSearch_1=&bRegex_1=false&bSearchable_1=true&bSortable_1=true&mDataProp_2=2&sSearch_2=&bRegex_2=false&bSearchable_2=true&bSortable_2=true&mDataProp_3=3&sSearch_3=&bRegex_3=false&bSearchable_3=true&bSortable_3=true&mDataProp_4=4&sSearch_4=&bRegex_4=false&bSearchable_4=true&bSortable_4=true&mDataProp_5=5&sSearch_5=&bRegex_5=false&bSearchable_5=true&bSortable_5=true&mDataProp_6=6&sSearch_6=&bRegex_6=false&bSearchable_6=true&bSortable_6=true&mDataProp_7=7&sSearch_7=&bRegex_7=false&bSearchable_7=true&bSortable_7=true&mDataProp_8=8&sSearch_8=&bRegex_8=false&bSearchable_8=true&bSortable_8=true&mDataProp_9=9&sSearch_9=&bRegex_9=false&bSearchable_9=true&bSortable_9=true&sSearch=&bRegex=false&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&export=csv, this url downloads a csv upon accessing it. How can this download be automated, with python?

Initially, I used selenium-python to automate login and to navigate through the website to obtain the url.
I tried using python requests.get where is sent the query string in the url as a dictionary. But this didn't work (only reads some html). I need this to be automated to download a large number of csv's from such url's. Thanks in advance.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(login_url)
driver.find_element('name','email').send_keys(u_name)
driver.find_element('name','pass').send_keys(pw)
driver.find_element('xpath','/html/body/div[1]/div/div/form/dl/dd[3]/button').click()
ele = driver.find_element('xpath',
                          "/html/body/div[1]/article/div[2]/section[4]/ul/li[1]/a")
cl_url = ele.get_attribute('href')
driver.get(cl_url)
xpath_idx = '/html/body/div[1]/div/ul/li['
xpath_suffix = ']/a'
xpath_ovr = xpath_idx + '10' + xpath_suffix
driver.find_element('xpath',xpath_ovr).click()

driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[10]/span[1]/a').click()
element = driver.find_element('xpath',
                              '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/section[4]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[2]/div/a[1]')

final_url = element.get_attribute('href')

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
data_dict = {}

query_idx = final_url.find('?')
q_list = final_url[query_idx+1:].split('&')
for i in q_list:
    tmp = i.split("=")
    data_dict[tmp[0]] = tmp[1]

response = requests.get(final_url[:query_idx+1], params=data_dict)
print(response.text)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: did you also send the cookie or token you got from authentication along with the request?

Comment: If you show the code you're struggling with we may be able to help you. Even better, if the website is in the public domain, let us know its URL rather than hiding it

Comment: I just started using selenium for the first time, don't know how to pass a cookie? I'll share the code and URL

Comment: the download website should end with `.csv`,  not `&export=csv`, or you should post the html detail.

Comment: @Jiu_Zou I don't think that's the issue. The structure of a url has nothing to do with the content of the returned document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you log in using your browser, you can use your debugging tools to see the headers set in the request, including any cookies.

Authentication is managed using the `cosmic_session` cookie. If you copy this value, you can then use it (until it expires) with the `requests` module to automate your downloads.

After registering with the website and logging in, I was able to download the link from your question using this code:

```
import requests

url = "https://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cell_lines/sample/mutations?id=1287381&sEcho=1&iColumns=10&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&mDataProp_0=0&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&bSortable_0=true&mDataProp_1=1&sSearch_1=&bRegex_1=false&bSearchable_1=true&bSortable_1=true&mDataProp_2=2&sSearch_2=&bRegex_2=false&bSearchable_2=true&bSortable_2=true&mDataProp_3=3&sSearch_3=&bRegex_3=false&bSearchable_3=true&bSortable_3=true&mDataProp_4=4&sSearch_4=&bRegex_4=false&bSearchable_4=true&bSortable_4=true&mDataProp_5=5&sSearch_5=&bRegex_5=false&bSearchable_5=true&bSortable_5=true&mDataProp_6=6&sSearch_6=&bRegex_6=false&bSearchable_6=true&bSortable_6=true&mDataProp_7=7&sSearch_7=&bRegex_7=false&bSearchable_7=true&bSortable_7=true&mDataProp_8=8&sSearch_8=&bRegex_8=false&bSearchable_8=true&bSortable_8=true&mDataProp_9=9&sSearch_9=&bRegex_9=false&bSearchable_9=true&bSortable_9=true&sSearch=&bRegex=false&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&export=csv"

sess = requests.Session()
sess.cookies["cosmic_session"] = "012345678901234567890123456789012345"

res = sess.get(url)
with open('data.csv', 'w') as fd:
    fd.write(res.text)
```

You would of course need to replace the value of the `cosmic_session` cookie.

Comment: Thanks, This worked! I was able to automate the whole downloading with selenium and requests module.